# ways to walk on a hexagon to return to same point with n steps

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recursion

So I have an hexagon and I start at point 1 and I can only move right or left, I need to find the formula to reach the same point within n steps,
Assuming I have an odd number of steps allowed, I can't ever return to the point.
But assuming I have even steps, I'm not sure how do I even think about it, I divided by two because I can go from 1>>2 or from 1>>6 so it's easier to just look at it as if i started with 1 step right.
This means that if the sequence is $ a_n $and I took a step right now i have $ a_{n-1}$ steps to come back.
how do I go on from here?

Comment: Try working with the number of ways to reach each of the six points after $n$ steps (so six variables) - there is a left-right symmetry which will help. Sometimes it is easier to make a problem look more complicated before simplifying. This way you record and control all the data.

Comment: Since you have made the realisation that you need an even number of steps, you can also think about moving around the hexagon two steps at a time though. This reduces your problem to moving around a triangle, where you may choose not to move at each 'double-step'. You have to take care however, since there are two ways to choose not to move.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I realize the mistake was going to $ a_{n-1} $ instead of $a_{n-2} but does it not complicate it even more? Im not sure if i can solve a polynomial of higher degree if i have to take another sub-sequence for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Another approach:**

While the situation is simple enough to describe it the way you did, I think the context of a walk on a graph naturally arises here: your graph is the (undirected) $6$-cycle. Let $A$ be its adjacency matrix, finding the number of ways to start from a given point $i$ and end at $i$ in $n$ steps is just the number of paths with length $n$ from $i$ to $i$. That number is given by computing $B = A^n$ and looking at $b_{ii}$.

Here $A$ is known:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0  &    1    &     0   &    0    &     0   &  1  \\
1   & 0 &  1 &  0 &    0    &  0 \\
0  & 1  &      0 &  1 & 0  &  0  \\
 0  &  0 & 1  &      0 & 1  &   0 \\
0   &    0    & 0  & 1 & 0 &  1 \\
1  &    0    &      0  &     0  &     1   & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$A$ is diagonalisable, making it possible to find a "simple" closed form for $A^n$. In the end, the result you are looking for is:
$$\frac{1}{6}\left (2(1+(-1)^n) + 2^n + (-2)^n \right)$$

However, as you noticed that for odd $n$, the result is always $0$, you can spare yourself some work and look directly at $A^2$ and find that the formula is $\frac{2^n + 2}{3}$ for even $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, unfortunately I haven't learnt matrix diagonalisation so I didn't really catch how you got that part.  As for the matrix itself you just took all the combinations where there is a 0 in between two steps?

Comment: OK. As regards how $A$ is obtained, it is the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of the 6-cycle. Put simply, $a_{ij}$ is the number of ways to go from node $i$ to node $j$. You can check that this matrix indeed describes the hexagon you mentioned. If you haven't learned diagonalisation, the basic idea is to decompose $A = PDP^{-1}$ with $P$ an invertible matrix and $D$ a diagonal matrix (making it much easier to find the $n$-th power of $A$). If you have not learned about it, then, a more traditional combinatorial approach is probably what is expected here.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a solution (although not a closed-form) for the general $N$-gon. Suppose we write out our sequence of moves as a list of $n$ letters, either $L$ or $R$ (for left and right). We want to count the number of possible lists of length $n$ where the number of $L$ exceeds the number of $R$ by a multiple of $N$.

This is done by choosing $k$ of these steps to be $L$ moves, such that the difference between $k$ and $n-k$ is an integer multiple of $N$. Hence, the total number of moves is
$$\sum_{k\in S}\binom{n}{k}$$
where $S=\{0\leq k\leq n:n-2k\in N\mathbb{Z}\}$, which we can rewrite as
$$k=\frac{n+mN}{2}$$
for all integers $|m|\leq n/N$. A closed form for this sum would clearly be desired however.

Comment: mind explaining how you got the sum part?  I understood that the amount of total steps has to be equal to 0(modN) but when you chose K steps to the left out of all n steps in total ,how did you come up with $n-2k $ ? didn't we just over complicate it with all the new variables?

Comment: Apologies, I made a small typo which I've correct. What I mean is that the *difference* between $k$ and $n-k$ needs to be an integer multiple of $N$. Furthermore, even though we introduced this variable $k$, the set $S$ is determined quite easily given any $n$ and $N$, and hence the number of steps can be calculated.